# MLT Framework how to make the length of the fragments varchar?

Tags: video, mlt

We do cutting rollers, very small in the MLT Framework http://www.mltframework.org/

How to specify a value for OUT source code (producer) in frames, a fractional number
for example now 27.0
and need 27.27

or perhaps work in seconds rather than frames?

if we simply write 27.27 is rounded

http://prntscr.com/5ktad9

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but the [API documentation](http://www.mltframework.org/doxygen/structmlt__property__s.html#a96ada1524a5677dc3d9f269c50048a11) for converting a property to an integer might be useful. MLT does not support a fraction of a frame; a single video frame is the precision. In addition, [this blog](http://mltframework.blogspot.com/2012/04/time-properties.html) post linked to from the main documentation page, contains more information.